# How to know when Fragment becomes invisible

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using ViewPager with PagerSlidingTabStrip , i have 3 fragments , every fragment has its own custom listeners. In every fragment I overrided Destroy, Pause methods, but unfortunately when I move from one fragment to other I have to remove listeners of One fragment but none of the above methods are called as fragments remain in memory.  These methods are only called when i am moving to another Activity.  So can any body tell me how can I know if a fragment is going to made invisible so that I can remove Listeners, otherwise these listeners are going to disturb that data for all my fragments.

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my fragment, this is called twice. 1) when you go out of screen 2) when fragment is first created. TO solve check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621490/3736955)

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible){
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        if (!visible){
            //when fragment becomes invisible to user,do what you want...
        }
}
```

Comment: setUserVisibleHint method called each time when it is visible to a user. Not only for first time it been created.

Comment: @DinIslamMilon i didn't say that, read again. This particular code is called twice `if(!visible)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `onPause()` and `onResume()` as `onDestroy()` only gets called when the fragment is removed from memory, not when it stops being run.

Also, in a paging setup, neighbouring fragments will continue to run. One on either side of current fragment.

For the visibility check you could check this thread:

[How to determine when Fragment becomes visible in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager)

Comment: yes right , so how can i know which fragment is going to be invisible?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a reference to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

With `ViewPager` you should better override `Fragment.setUserVisibleHint()` `Fragment.onHiddenChanged()` and react on visible/hidden state change. You still need to implement `onPause()` / `onResume()`. I explained it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23701138/1219199) in more details.