# ViewPager showing Mediacontrols on Imageview ahead of VideoView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gallery, mediacontroller

**Gallery feature:**

I am developing a feature similar to Gallery, where users can swipe to see image or video uploaded by them.

**Problem :**

*Whenever there is video after imageview, Mediacontrols for videoview is getting displayed on imageview for about 2 seconds*

[image: Image showing Mediacontrols]

***Code :***

**item_pager.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:background="@color/black_overlay"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/images_pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="250dp"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:visibility="visible"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/cctv_icon" />

  <VideoView
   android:id="@+id/videoview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="250dp"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:visibility="gone" />
 </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

***PagerAdapter code :***

```
public class ItemViewpager extends PagerAdapter implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, 
   View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener {
 private List<MediaInfo> mediaInfos;
 private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
 private MediaController mediaController;
 private HashMap<Integer, MediaController> mediaMap;
 private VideoView videoView;
 private ImageView imageView;
 private int currPos = 0;

 public ItemViewpager(List<MediaInfo> mediaInfos) {
  this.mediaInfos = mediaInfos;
  mediaMap = new HashMap<>(mediaInfos.size());
 }

@Override
public int getCount() {
return mediaInfos.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
 return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
 layoutInflater= 
  (LayoutInflater)container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager, container, false);

   imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.images_pager);
   videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
   videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
   videoView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

   boolean video = mediaInfos.get(position).video;
   String uri = mediaInfos.get(position).uri;

   mediaController = new MediaController(container.getContext());
   mediaMap.put(position, mediaController);
  if (video) {
     imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
     mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
     videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
     videoView.requestFocus();
     videoView.seekTo(1);
   } else {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
   }
  if (mediaMap.size() > 0)
   mediaMap.get(position).hide();

container.addView(itemView);

return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
 container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

}

public void onPageSelectionListener(int pos) {
  currPos = pos;
  boolean video = mediaInfos.get(currPos).video;

  /*if (mediaMap.size() > 0) {
   if (video)
    mediaMap.get(currPos).show(0);
   else
    mediaMap.get(currPos).hide();
  }*/
  }


  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
  boolean video = mediaInfos.get(currPos).video;

   /*if (!video)
    videoView.stopPlayback();
   else
    mediaMap.get(currPos).show();*/
    }

   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focus) {
   }

  }
```

Thanks in advance :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my issue got **resolved** by [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096868/how-can-make-my-viewpager-load-only-one-page-at-a-time-ie-setoffscreenpagelimit/44405015#44405015) given by **Ronak Thakkar**

The **CustomViewpager** used had tried to load only single page by various ways.

You can always see the **source code** in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (video) {
     imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
     mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
     videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
     videoView.requestFocus();
     videoView.seekTo(1);
   } else {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //add below line, hide mediaController
    videoView.setMediaController(null);
    Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
   }
```

This code hide mediaController:

```
videoView.setMediaController(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by below way

```
    boolean video = mediaInfos.get(currPos).video;
    if(video){
        mediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// You need the object of mediaController which is of currently visible videoView on the screen
    }else{
        mediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    }
```

Comment: Still the same result

Answer (score 0):

First create obj of mediacontroller. Then need to show it, call view.VISIBLE, when need to hide ,call view.gone.

```
 MediaController ctrl = new MediaController(context);

if(video){
     ctrl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
videoView.setMediaController(ctrl);

    }else{
       ctrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to change your `ViewPager` **adapter** from `PagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Meaning you will have to deal with fragments and lifecycle. You will have to put your VideoView/ImageView inside Fragment and instantiate video playing only when user sees `VideoView`. That's how you will get rid of `MediaController` showing on images. Method in which you should load video playing inside fragment is this one:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

When flag **isVisibleToUser** is true, you start playing video.
You can check for more help here: 
[Video is not pausing in fragment ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301728/video-is-not-pausing-in-fragment-viewpager?rq=1)

Google for more details, there are tons of examples how can you achieve what you want. I'm also suggesting for video playing, that you should get rid of **VideoView** and learn how to play videos with `ExoPlayer`, it's more complex to play videos but in the end it's much better optimised and performant solution to go with.

Also try to avoid using **ViewPager** for future, there is already new component, **`ViewPager2`** based on RecyclerView.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I dont want to use fragments because I think my problem can be resolved without creating lot of fragment instances.